# html and angularjs and ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

when i login the url bar going to first.html page. And URL bar showing like this "http://localhost:8100/templates/template/first/first.html". So easily all will know the path of first.html. So in order to hide what should be code write in html or in angularjs. 
After login URL bar shows like this http://localhost:8100/
So what is the code we have to write to do this

Comment: Make the page load through ajax. That way the URL will not change.

Comment: I want to help but its hard to understand the post, can you make the clear a bit clearer?

Comment: ionic doesn't show url's its a phone app...

Comment: use the angular router to define paths

Comment: To nCore:      i did that work in ionic. ionic framework means totally mobile based, so no need of worry about address (url) bar in mobile. My headache is only when u run in system and sign-in into the app, then immediately it jumps into the next page, all that is visible in the address bar like http://localhost:8100/templates/template/first/first.html . And one more information is that all code written in angularjs and ionic and html only.